# How do I stop MySQL from loading Mono libraries when it won't start?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mono

I am getting an error when I try to start MySQL on my Ubuntu Server 9.04 machine:

> /usr/sbin/mysqld: /etc/mono-1.9/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr/sbin/mysqld)

This prevents the MySQL daemon from starting. It appears that Mono integrates into MySQL, but I am not sure how this is done. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Mono does not integrate into MySQL (that I know of), but it sounds like the version of libz that ships with Mono is being given priority over the one that ships with Linux (typically in /usr/lib or /usr/lib64).  You should probably check your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, and anything else that affects where shared libraries are loaded from.

P.S.  You may want to take a look at [this page](http://dufoli.wordpress.com/2007/12/23/libxml2so-issue-with-mono-126/).  I must admit I only scanned it, but it sounds like /usr/lib/libz.so.1 is a symbolic link, and something about working with Mono (building MonoDevelop?) can cause this symbolic link to be re-pointed to the wrong version of libz.  Check if this is what happened to you.

I can confirm that on my RHEL system, /usr/lib/libz.so.1 is a symbolic link to /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib64/libz.so.1*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    13 Jun 28  2007 /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 85928 Jul 19  2006 /usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.3

$ ls -l /usr/lib/libz.so.1*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    13 Jun 28  2007 /usr/lib/libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 75284 Jul 19  2006 /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3
```